# VirtualHost problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

Can someone tell me why I can't view my index.php from the subdir `/oorbellenboutique/`?

It shows `http:// www.oorbellenboutique.nl/startpagina/index.php`, but it must be the index.php from `f:/inetpub/wwwroot/oorbellenboutique`

The correct URL is: `http:// www.oorbellenboutique.nl/index.php`

My DNS is:

```
A   *.oorbellenboutique.nl      →   83.87.163.224

A   oorbellenboutique.nl    →   83.87.163.224

CNAME   www.oorbellenboutique.nl    →   oorbellenboutique.nl
```

My URL is: http://www.oorbellenboutique.nl

I'm running Apache 2.x

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.199:80

NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.199:443
```

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.199:80 192.168.0.199:443>
ServerName oorbellenboutique.nl
ServerAlias www.oorbellenboutique.nl
DocumentRoot f:/inetpub/wwwroot/oorbellenboutique
RewriteEngine On
KeepAlive Off
DocumentRoot "f:/inetpub/wwwroot"
    <Directory f:/inetpub/wwwroot/oorbellenboutique>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oorbellenboutique\.nl$
ReWriteRule ^(.*) /oorbellenboutique/$1
</virtualhost>
```

---

**This works but the URL is now:**

**http:// www.oorbellenboutique.nl/oorbellenboutique/index.php**

**How can I make the URL shorter like:**

**http:// www.oorbellenboutique.nl/index.php**

NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.199:80

NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.199:443

< VirtualHost 192.168.0.199:80 192.168.0.199:443>

ServerName www.oorbellenboutique.nl

ServerAlias *.oorbellenboutique.nl oorbellenboutique.nl

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?oorbellenboutique.nl$

```
<Directory f:/inetpub/wwwroot/oorbellenboutique>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

RewriteRule ^/$ /oorbellenboutique/ [R]

< /virtualhost>

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a RewriteBase directive immediately following the RewriteEngine directive:

```
RewriteBase f:/inetpub/wwwroot
```

That is not the same as DocumentRoot for functionality -- it is needed for mod_rewrite.